# Writing char array to NetCDF file with julia

Tags: julia, netcdf

How can I add an array of chars in a NetCDF file with julia? Below is a code example. First of all, it already gives an error for writing a string array, so there might be something wrong. But actually, I need "country" to be of type Char. How can I change the string array to Char for use in NetCDF? This appears related to this issue (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17694), but I don't see how to solve it.

Example:

```
using NetCDF
filename="test_netcdf_string.nc"
# Define some attributes
varatts = Dict("longname" => "number of citizens","units" => "million")
timeatts = Dict("longname" => "Time","units"    => "year")
nameatts = Dict("longname" => "Country name")

#Add some random data
time_data=collect(2014:2017)
countries=["Italy ","Germany", "France "]
cit_numbers=rand(5:100,size(countries,1),size(time_data,1))

#Create variable in netcdf
nccreate(filename, "citizens", "country", countries, nameatts,
"time", time_data, timeatts, atts=varatts)

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching nc_put_vara_x(::NetCDF.NcVar{Float64,1,6}, ::Array{UInt64,1}, ::Array{UInt64,1}, ::Array{String,1})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to do this with the package `NetCDF.jl`, but here is a way to do this with the julia package `NCDatasets.jl`.

```
using NCDatasets

filename="test_netcdf_string.nc"

time_data=collect(2014:2017)
countries=["Italy ","Germany", "France "]
cit_numbers=rand(5:100,size(countries,1),size(time_data,1))

ds = Dataset(filename,"c")
# define the dimensions
defDim(ds,"countries",length(countries))
defDim(ds,"time",length(time_data))

# define the variables
nccit_numbers = defVar(ds,"cit_numbers",Float64,("countries","time"))
nccountries = defVar(ds,"countries",String,("countries",))
nctime = defVar(ds,"time",Float64,("time",))

# define the attributes
nccountries.attrib["longname"] = "Country name"
# add more attributes...

nccountries[:] = countries
nccit_numbers[:] = cit_numbers
nctime[:] = time_data

# closing the file to make sure the data is saved
close(ds)
```

Running the julia command `Dataset(filename)` returns:

```
Dataset: test_netcdf_string.nc
Group: /

Dimensions
   countries = 3
   time = 4

Variables
  cit_numbers   (3 × 4)
    Datatype:    Float64
    Dimensions:  countries × time

  countries   (3)
    Datatype:    String
    Dimensions:  countries
    Attributes:
     longname             = Country name

  time   (4)
    Datatype:    Float64
    Dimensions:  time
```

If somebody could add an answer for the package `NetCDF.jl`, this would be helpful.

Note that writing list (or arrays) of strings to a NetCDF file has been added to the NetCDF library since version 4. You will find a lot of documentation about the NetCDF library 3 where you could only write a vector (or arrays) of single characters. In this case, you would need to make all country names of equal length (by padding them with whitespace for example or the null character) and assemble all these names into a matrix. Luckily this is no longer necessary with NetCDF 4.

Comment: Thanks for your help!